# Ajax jquery - instant load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a live updating div on my website. It works fine however the user always have to wait 5 seconds before it loads. Heres my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            setInterval(function() {
                $('#div-id').load('/something.php');
            }, 5000);
        });
</script>
```

Is there a way I can load, it then wait 5 seconds and load it again? Instead of wait 5 seconds, load it, then wait again...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. jQuery's `load()` method has a [*complete* callback function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) as a parameter:

> `.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )`
>
> **complete**
> A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

Thanks to this we can create a *recursive* function which calls itself once complete (or in this case, after 5 seconds):

```
function loadContent(selector, path) {
    $(selector).load(path, function() {
        setTimeout( loadContent(selector, path), 5000 );
    });
}

loadContent('#div-id', '/something.php');
```

What I've done here is move your content loading logic into a new function called `loadContent`, which accepts a selector and a path as its parameters. This function then triggers `load()` on the passed in selector, loading the passed in path. When the content has loaded a `setTimeout` function kicks in to trigger our `loadContent` function once again after 5000 millisecond (5 seconds).

Triggering `loadContent()` to begin with will fire our function off immediately, meaning you will not have to wait 5 seconds before the content first loads.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run your ajax manually before first interval run.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var loadContent = function() {
            $('#div-id').load('/something.php');
        };
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            loadContent();
            setInterval(loadContent, 5000);
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `load` once before

```
$('#div-id').load('/something.php');
setInterval(function() {
     $('#div-id').load('/something.php');
}, 5000);
```